# When should I mark the Summer/Winter Courtier condition?

Tags: fate-core, dresden-files, fate-accelerated, dresden-files-accelerated

Dresden Files Accelerated introduces a new way to use Conditions, by turning some ability on/off (The Third Eye, for example).

Some of them, however (which are always marked), doesn't look much different from a Stunt.

The Summer and Winter Court True Fae Mantles (pg 160, pg 162), have a *Summer/Winter Courtier* condition which handles:

- Know the court important players and have heard rumors
- Being expected to appear occasionally before the Lady or Queens and be entangled in the court affairs
- Have a court ally and a rival

But there is no mention on when the Condition is marked or how it is recovered. So...

- In which situation the player should mark the *Summer/Winter Courtier* condition?
- When marked, what are its benefits or drawbacks?
- How does the player recover from this condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A mantle is an organized set of related stunts and conditions reflecting
> how its possessor leverages their power in the world. At character creation,
> each player gains access to their selected mantle’s conditions and core stunts.

- DFA page 119

Conditions are sorted out into three forms on p116, but the ability in question is the 4th (Special). *Every other example* of (Special) Conditions starts with the lines

- This condition is always marked, (unless...)

or for the case of Truth-Bound, which is also marked

- You are incapable of outright lies.

---

### (Season) Courtier could be a typo.

If so, it should be the same as the others. The ability is always checked and is just there to remind you of your responsibilities.

### However, I believe it was intentional.

The box should be checked *when* you

> are expected to appear occasionally with the rest of Winter before the Lady and/
> or Queen

or

> [are] entangled in Court intrigues

It is at these times that you can call on your ally to support you and expect your rival to attempt to confound your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

They should always be checked.  Just like the Truthbound condition, they're aspects that are always present on your character.  They're done as conditions to represent the fact that the DM can hit you with a compel on them any time they choose, and that you're always bound and effected by their limits.

You can't recover from them -- they're a part of your mantle, again, just like Truthbound.